# AWK from a second column and grep it in 2 files

Tags: unix

I have a query wherein I am taking the value from second column from a file and searching if it is present in another 2 file
If it returns true then I execute a set of commands, if it returns false then there are another set of commands.

After execution the loop has to again go into the second column and search from second row, how do I do this ?

I have tried the below:

for i in $(cat file1.txt) ; do grep $i *ary.txt ; done

This is not working for me, if I simply extract the column 2 contents and display it in a file then it will grep and give me the Output
What am I missing

Comment: I don't see any second column that you select from. If your second columns aren't too long you could `branches=$(awk '{print "\\|"$2}' file1.txt|tr -d ' '|sed 's/^\\\|//'); grep "$branches" *ary.txt` (untested)

Comment: Thanks it helped :)